# react native router flux custom navbar access to method component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a Scene with custom navbar

```
                <Scene
                      navBar={CustomNavBar}
                      component={MComponent}                   

                  />
```

MyCOmponent have on method called _hello()

```
 export default class MComponentextends PureComponent {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);     
     }
   _hello = () => {
    console.warn('HELLO WORLD')
}
```

Is it possible to call MyComponent _hello() method inside my navbar component ?

```
export default class CustomNavBar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {        
    };
    this.props._hello () // does not work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Scene as mediator.

first, add a callback prop to CustomNavBar in Scene

```
<CustomNavBar cb={this._callback}>
```

then set ref for MyComponent, also in Scene

```
<MyComponent ref={(c)=>this._myComponent=c}>
```

when you want to call _hello in CustomNavBar, call cb instead

```
this.props.cb();
```

and _callback in Scene will be called, use this._myComponent to call _hello

```
this._myComponent._hello()
```

Comment: passing props to Scene CustomNavBar throw error => Check the method of cardstack

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Scene 
navBar={CustomNavBar cb={this._callback}} 
component={MComponentef={(c)=>this._myComponent=c}}
/>
```

passing props to Scene CustomNavBar throw error => Check the method of cardstack